# Match the animals, three by three

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**Match the animals, three by three**

Beagle
Dalmatian
Dog
Pug
Puppy
Retriever

Accipitridae
Anura
Arthropod
Castor
Gastropoda
Poecilia

**Instructions**

There are two lists, each containing six items. The lists are currently in alphabetical order. You may rearrange the order of any given list.

Create a third list and thus match all the lists in groups of three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building off of Matthew Jensen's answer:

> Beagle Accipitridae Eagle
>  Dalmation Arthropod Crustacean (Previous guess: Exclamation Damsel)
>  Dog Anura Frog
>  Pug Gastropod Slug
>  Puppy Poecilia Guppy
>  Retriever Castor Beaver

Where:

> Each of the second columns is a scientific classification (Kingdom, Phylum, Class, Order, Family, etc) containing an animal in the third column which rhymes with an animal in the first column.

Comment: Well done! It seems so obvious now what the third list is...

Answer (score 3):

A Partial answer (maybe)

> Found possible pairings for 5/6 words
>  - Beagle & Accipitridae (super-category of (B)Eagle)
>  - Dalmatian (spotted dog) & Poecilia (spotted fish)
>  - Dog & Anura (Frog, both end with 'og')
>  - Pug & Arthropod (Bug, both end with 'ug')
>  - Puppy & Gastropoda (slugs & snails & puppy dogs' tails, from the nursery rhyme 'What are Little Boys Made of?')

I have no idea what the third list would be, though...

Comment: You are on the right track. Your 1 and 3 are correct. They also contain the correct elements of the third list. Your 4 looks plausible but it won't fit if you get the others all correct.